# incorrect response in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

i'm new at nodejs & angular
here is my restAPI function :

```
  exports.getPlanningStages = async (req, res, next) => {
  const currentPage = req.query.page || 1;
  const perPage = 2;
  try {
    const totalItems = await Planningstage.find().countDocuments();
    const planningstages = await Planningstage.find()
      .populate('creator')
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
      .limit(perPage);

    res.status(200).json({
      planningstages
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
   }
  };
```

at the console i see the correct response json array
the angular code is

**planningstage.service.ts**

```
private ps: Planningstage[] = [];
  getPlanningStages() {
    return this.httpService
    .get<Planningstage[]>(
      "http://localhost:8080/planningstage/getPlanningStage"
    );
}
```

**planningstage.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetch();
  }

  fetch() {
     this.psService.getPlanningStages().subscribe(resData => {
           console.log(resData);
     });
```

the response at the browser
[browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g42UN.png)

how can i read the currect response at my angular code

thank's

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is with this line,

```
res.status(200).json({
      planningstages
    });
```

instead of above line, make like this

```
res.status(200).json(planningstages);
```